# How to choose a profile in AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, okta

I am entering aws through okta and I am stuck. I did all the necessary stuff from cloning the okta repo to downloading aws cli to my ubuntu machine. I identified myself with my username, password and push notification. Next I choose a role. After that I am getting such a message (look picture). How can I choose this profile? Without choosing this profile I am getting access denied :(.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it!
I needed to type in: aws-okta switch  region